# Elasticsearch and the Terms filter AND execution mode

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm losing my mind over how to achieve a filtered query that matches on having 'all' the provided terms, not 'any', basically 'and' vs 'or'.

Given I have (a very simplified version) a document:

```
{
    "content": {
        "tags": [
            {
                "tag": "Express",
                "type": "other"
            },
            {
                "tag": "Baking",
                "type": "other"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Currently I have the following for a search:

```
{
    "min_score": 0.5,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {},
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "content.tags",
                            "filter": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "content.tags.tag": ["Express", "Baking"],
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                    "should": []
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": ["_score"],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 12
}
```

I understand that this will look for any documents that have 'Express' and also add to that any documents that have 'Baking'. What I need is a filter that matches only documents that have both tags present.

I've read the docs, and my understanding of them was that I needed to add `"execution": "and"` into the filter as such

```
{
    "min_score": 0.5,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {},
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "content.tags",
                            "filter": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "content.tags.tag": ["Express", "Baking"],
                                    "execution": "and"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                    "should": []
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": ["_score"],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 12
}
```

Sadly, this matches 0 documents, when I know for a fact there are 28 of them.

My `content.tags.tag` field is not analyzed, and `content.tags` has many nested objects as described above, so I understood it to mean that it must contain one of each tag, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: I'll mention too, I have left the main body of the query empty here, and I'm just concerned with the filters in this question. I have other query parts that bear no reflection to the issue, and work as expected.

Comment: What version of ES are you using? 2.0 ignores the execution option (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html)

Comment: Hi, I'm still on 1.7 as it's a production server, so lucky in that respect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is a nested document that contains both terms `"Express"` and `"Baking"`, which does not match the (parent) document you listed. It has a nested document that matches the first term, and another nested document that matches the second, but no nested documents that match both. And as @Frederick pointed out, your second query won't work in Es 2.0 anyway.

On the other hand, when I tried your query, I got no results anyway, because your empty query clause matches nothing. But when I removed it the document was returned, as was a document that matched either of the terms but not both. (if the `"execution": "and"` hadn't been ignored, it would have returned none of the documents).

Anyway, it sounds like this is what you are asking for: find a parent document containing nested documents that match each of the two terms:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "content.tags",
                  "filter": {
                     "term": {
                        "content.tags.tag": "Express"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "content.tags",
                  "filter": {
                     "term": {
                        "content.tags.tag": "Baking"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to test all this (in ES 2.1):

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/e375721509acbb5170e07eb969ea4409921f42d3

Comment: I only emptied the query clause for the example as I mentioned in my comment. Thanks for the response though, I can't believe that I have to create a separate filter for each term, as in reality there could be up to 20 of them :(

Answer (score 1):

Use two different must condition,

```
{
    "min_score": 0.5,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {},
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "content.tags",
                            "filter": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "content.tags.tag": "Banking"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },"nested": {
                            "path": "content.tags",
                            "filter": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "content.tags.tag": "Express"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                    "should": []
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": ["_score"],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 12
}
```

Comment: I chose another response as it had an explanation, but thanks very much for replying :D

Comment: I believe his is better one, just we sent as the same time. Even I vote for his answer :)